# Processing failed messages + Performance + camel route execution

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I have many routes defined as a part of application flow.I will pick the failed messages and will forward to the route in order to get processed.

Here iam just picking the failed messages and forwarding it to the normal route flow of the application(where it got failed previously due to external factors).
Will this affect the performance/increase the load of the normal application flow.
Want to analyse the hit by doing this.

I understand that this above will be considered as a new request.
Any comments? Pls let me know that my understanding is correct.

Each route in camel will be executed in a separate thread?

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just an extra message to process. So the overhead is just what it takes to process one more message. And that is negligible on most systems.

So no there is no performance impact.

Comment: That was my understanding too.Thanks.